# get segments of constant length from Linestring MS SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

For Example I have simple linestring 'LINESTRING(25 50, 100 125, 150 190)' and I need to divide it to segments of length 10. In postgis i know there is a function [ST_Segmentize](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Segmentize.html) but what about MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are after the SQL Server Spatial Tools extras for SQL Server 2008.  Find them and the descriptions at

http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Current%20Contents&referringTitle=Home

Be aware that after you install, you have to trust the assembly as well.

Once you have these installed, then it given you a few more options.  One of which is to LocateAlongGeom, which will give you a point a given distance in whatever the units are of the geometry along the line.

`select dbo.LocateAlongGeom(geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(25 50, 100 125, 150 190)',0),10)`

Comment: thank you and I forgot to ask whether it will be capable of ms sql server express 2008?

Comment: Yes you can use it in SQL SERVER 2008 Express, I just checked my local install and it works fine.